# How do I use c++20/23 std::views to create a map of <key1, map<key2, results>>?

Tags: c++, std-ranges, c++23

I would like to know if it's possible to do the following better with `std::views`, which is doing some compute function on an input struct and putting it into a `unordered_map<string, unordered_map<string, results_t>>` results container of `some attribute of struct as key1 -> some other attribute of struct as key2 -> result`

I have:

```
struct results_t {
    int someNum;
    string someString;
};

struct example_t {
    string attribute0;
    string attribute1;
};

results_t computeResults(const example_t& input) {
    return { 0, "A" };
}
```

The equivalent function I want using for loops is:

```
vector<example_t> stuff = { {"Food", "Bread"}, {"Food", "Apple"}, {"Animal", "Cat"}, {"Animal", "Dog"} };
unordered_map<string, unordered_map<string, results_t>> container = {};

for (const auto& thing : stuff) {
    const auto result = computeResults(thing);
    if (!container.contains(thing.attribute0))
        container.insert({ thing.attribute0, {} });
    container.at(thing.attribute0).insert({ thing.attribute1, result });
}
```

I got as far as the following:

```
auto v = stuff | views::transform([](const auto& thing) { return make_pair(thing.attribute1, computeResults(thing)); })
```

But I can't pipe this into a `ranges::to<unordered_map<string, results_t>>` since I haven't filtered by `attribute0` yet.

I think I need a filter on each possible `attribute0`, if I had that I can do:

```
auto uniqueAttribute0 = stuff | views::transform([](const auto & thing) { return thing.attribute0; })
    | ranges::to<unordered_set<std::string>>()

auto v = uniqueAttribute0
    | views::transform([&](const auto& key0) {
            auto innermap = stuff | filter([&](const auto& thing){ return thing.attribute0 == key0});
                | views::transform([](const auto& thing)
                    { return make_pair(thing.attribute1, computeResults(thing)); })
                | ranges::to<unordered_map<string, results_t>>();
            return make_pair(key0, innermap)
        })
    | ranges::to<unordered_map<string, unordered_map<string, results_t>>>()
```

However this means I have to read the container of `stuff` and get all the unique `attribute0` first, whereas my for loop example only needs to read the container once. Is there a better way to do this with c++20/c++23 views and ranges?

Comment: Your not making a view, you are creating a new datastructure so why not just use std::transform?

Comment: `map of <key1, map<key2, results>>` That's complicated. Why not `map<tuple<key1,key2>,results>?

Comment: It seems like your for-loop can be simplified to just `for (const auto& thing : stuff)
    container[thing.attribute0][thing.attribute1] = computeResults(thing);`

Comment: @康桓瑋 Thanks, I actually forgot I was able to do this with nested maps

Comment: @PepijnKramer Combining with using `container[thing.attribute0][thing.attribute1] ` I guess it all simplifies down to a for_each instead of transform

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI I didn't want a tuple because I wanted to filter by attribute0 quickly. I'm not sure with a tuple if I can get all by tuple<attribute0, any attribute1>

Comment: For unordered maps it's indeed not possible,

Comment: Edit: I didn't know how to respond with a code block here as the formatting got all wonky so I posted an answer response updating my solution.

Answer (score 1):

Combining the responses, I think I have now:

```
auto attr0 = stuff | views::transform([](const auto & thing){ return thing.attribute0; });
auto attr1Objects = stuff | views::transform([](const auto & thing) { return make_pair(thing.attribute1, computeResults(thing)); });

ranges::for_each(views::zip(attr0, attr1Objects), [&](const auto& zElement) { const auto& [attr0, obj] = zElement; container[attr0].insert(obj); })
```

I think this solves my problem. Ignoring how this looks more complicated than a simple for-loop (just wanted some ranges/views practice)

However, I'm not sure how under the hood views work, does the first two autos defined basically cause two loops through `stuff`, as in two iterators incrementing at the same time? I guess if so, this could be made better by just combining the two `auto view` into a single one that returns a tuple, then in the for_each lambda un-tuple this.